# overridden onHandlerNotFound not being called in Global.java

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to override the default behavior for handling errors in the play framework 2.1.1 but I'm having problems with 404s, basically my overridden onHandlerNotFound doesn't seem to be being called. When I visit a page that doesn't exist all that happens is a blank page is returned. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  My Global.java is below

```
import play.GlobalSettings;
import play.mvc.Http.RequestHeader;
import play.mvc.Result;
import play.mvc.Results;
import views.html.error;


public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

    @Override
    public Result onHandlerNotFound(RequestHeader request) {
        return Results.notFound(error.render());
    }

    @Override
    public Result onError(RequestHeader request, Throwable t) {
        return Results.internalServerError(error.render());
    }
}
```

By the way, the onError override is working.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so the problem in this case was that the route for assets had been changed to

```
GET     /*file                      controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

changing it back to the default of

```
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

made it work again. I don't fully understand why it stopped working, can anyone explain?

Comment: The Global.onHandlerNotFound() method is called for requests that don't match any rule in the routes file. Well, by removing the "assets/" portion from the route you told Play to handle any request (that didn't match a previous route) via the default Assets controller. So the request you expected to 404 was actually going through the Assets controller, which apparently, just returns a 404 with no content if it doesn't find the static asset.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is valid and works, but the behaviour *should* be caused by the browser. I tested this by using your code and going to a non-existing page in Firefox and the error page is rendered and shown.

When I try the same with Internet Explorer, it breaks (empty page).

The solution is relatively simple, use an `ok` instead of `notFound`:

```
@Override
public Result onHandlerNotFound(RequestHeader request) {
    return Results.ok(error.render());
}
```

The same goes for a `badRequest`, I haven't tested any others.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still not working. Even if I change the return statement to ok(error.render()). The actual method is not getting called. No page is rendered when a 404 happens - just a blank screen with a 404 response code.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and I am using play 2.3.4 , the solution for me was to explicitly say `Results.notFound(...)` instead of just `notFound(...)`

Here is my function

```
@Override
public F.Promise<Result> onHandlerNotFound(Http.RequestHeader request) {
    return F.Promise.<Result>pure(Results.notFound(views.html.notfoundPage.render(request.uri())));
}
```

DO NOT FORGET to clean up your project (`play clean, or activator clean`) after this change.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for an answer, I think this should help.

```
@Override
public Promise<SimpleResult> onHandlerNotFound(RequestHeader request) {
    return Promise.<SimpleResult>pure(notFound(
            views.html.notFoundPage.render(request.uri())
    ));
}
```